# KeepAliveHD not activating for an external hard drive (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

My external HDD keeps going to sleep. I've gone into Windows power settings, and set `USB selective suspend` setting to disabled.

I've set all USB root hubs to not be powered off to conserve power.

These settings did not prevent the external HDD from disappearing from Windows 10 file explorer.

I download [KeepAliveHD](https://keepalivehd.codeplex.com/) which used to work for me, but now will not allow the setting for my G drive on my external HDD to become Enabled.

[image]

If I click "Accept" here it remains disabled.

How can I keep my external hard drives awake?

Help appreciated.

Comment: KeepAliveHD should have worked - you could try instead the similar [NoSleepHD](http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/). Ensure you are using the High performance power plan. For good measures you could in Change Plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Hard Disk > Turn off hard disk after, set the value to 0 (setting intended for internal disks but may apply). You are not alone: There are many reports about Windows 10 having botched sleep for external disks.

Comment: The NoSleepHD does not download properly from its [downloads webpage](http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/downloads/get/63700).

Comment: It downloads fine, but I found that it needs to be run as administrator.

Comment: @ [the download page](http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/downloads/get/63700) nothing happens. If I click `Click here if your browser does not start the download automatically` nothing happens also.

Comment: I clicked the big Download button on the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the "Enable writing mode" checkbox, then you will see the status for your G:\ drive will become ENABLED.

[image: Enable writing mode checkbox]